# Issues in jQuery Sliding Sidebar Panel Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery Sliding Sidebar Panel Plugin is not working. I want it to open with a single click, but it takes 3 button clicks to open the slide panel. I wrote the below code in my main.html page

```
<html> <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slidepanel.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-slidepanel]').slidepanel({
                 orientation: 'right',
                 mode: 'overlay'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="divButton">
        <a href="slide.html" data-slidepanel="panel" ><button>Control Panel</button></a>
    </div>

</body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following file also....

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.slidepanel.css">
```

Comment: I already added the above style sheet in the second script,But anyways i added once again but its not working.

Comment: could you please upload your code on JSFiddle and share the link please